# Why I can not get message pusher in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pusher

Here is a private channel:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    // Here I get $user object successfully
    return new PrivateChannel('user-'.$this->user->id); // it is 1
}
```

The permissions are:

```
Broadcast::channel('user-{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

The sender is:

```
Route::post('sender', function () {
    PrivateEvent::dispatch(Auth::user());
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

The client was tested in pusher debug console, it works:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('user-1');
channel.bind('PrivateEvent', function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Why when I send message using routing I dont get the message in JS? JS has not errors too.

Comment: I tried to replace `return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;` on return true. No result

Comment: Did you check websocket connection of the pusher in the development tool?